# Visual Studio for Mac is failing to find .Net 6.0 or .Net 5.0 on upgrading to VS Mac 8.10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, .net-6.0

I have upgraded to latest version of Visual Studio for Mac 8.10, also have installed .Net 6.0 SDK. While the installation was successful, the projects are failing to compile with error message saying "it is not finding .Net 6.0". The same projects were building just fine with .Net 5.0 before upgrade.

Exact error message:
`/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/MSBuild/7750_1/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(5,5): Error NETSDK1005: Assets file '/Users/myusername/Documents/myProjectName/myproject.Core/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v5.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net50' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. (NETSDK1005`)

Comment: Try to test is .net installed correctly or not try `dotnet --version` and then build the project with the .net cli try `dotnet build` and tell us the result.

Comment: dotnet 
zsh: command not found: dotnet

I have installed both .Net SDK 5.0.403 and 6.0.

Comment: Are you using an M1 machine (Arm64)?

Comment: Turns out that VS for Mac 2019 doesn't support .Net 6. 
We need VS for Mac 2022. Installed its Preview version and it worked.